# inner join and sum()

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, inner-join

I Have two tables
trips_data which as tripid, userid, species (int),killcount
masterspecies which had species_id and speceies (string)

I am trying to retrieve a list of all species seen on a trip
I am hoping to get

```
sum(killcount) : tripid :species (string):species (int)
57                 300    rabbit            1
2                  300    foxes             2 
1                  300    squirels          8
```

and so on
i have the below query which returns everything I want except the sum(killcount) is about 8000 when it should be 57.

Any help would be hugely apreciated

```
SELECT sum(trips_data.killcount), 
  trips_data.species,trips_data.spceces,
  masterspecies.species 
from trips_data 
join masterspecies 
WHERE tripid=$tripid 
   AND userid=1 
   AND NOT killcount=0
```

Comment: You aren't actually joining your table on the `species_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a cartesian join:

```
from trips_data join masterspecies
```

This will return a record for every combination of records from the two tables.  That is usually not the intention.  Join conditions look something like this:

```
from trips_data
join masterspecies
on masterspecies.species_id = trips_data.species_id
```

This will match the records up and only return matching records, so there is a chance your sum will come out correctly.

Comment: SELECT sum(trips_data.killcount), trips_data.species,masterspecies.species from trips_data join masterspecies on masterspecies.speciesidno = trips_data.species 
WHERE tripid=335 AND userid=1 AND NOT killcount=0
group by trips_data.species

Comment: adding in the on statement made it work thank you and everyone else who commented

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell the database how to join; otherwise you're getting every possible combination.  It looks like trips_data.species should match master_species.species_id; is that right?  You also need to group the results by species.

```
SELECT sum(trips_data.killcount), trips_data.species, masterspecies.species 
from trips_data join masterspecies
WHERE tripid=$tripid AND userid=1 and trips_data.species=masterspecies.species_id
group by trips_data.species, masterspecies.species;
```